# Reading a .dat file and saving to a matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have some matrices in Matlab that I need to load as arrays in C. I used the `dlmwrite` function in MATLAB to do this. Can someone link to a tutorial on how to load in C? Or maybe there’s already a function someone has written that can do this?

Also, just curious how long this process takes to load. The matrices aren’t terribly large, with the largest being 3136 by 2. I’ve switched to C for this particular application since it’s proving to be much faster than MATLAB, but I don’t want to slow the C code down too much by loading too much stuff.

I’m being a bit lazy by not translating part of my code to C (it’s a mesh generator that I didn’t write, so I don’t know the finer details), but this would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: What part of "loading data from a file into an array" are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

There is a C API for reading MATLAB .MAT files.

http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html

Comment: Thanks. One question though it where to get the mat.h and matrix.h headers. I just get a fatal error at compile. Is there a link to download them? Not much luck searching on the math works site